# How to create typedef for ``boost::array_view`` in a templated class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I want to have a dimensional agnostic template (usefull for both 3d and 4d), most of operations will be performed on submatrices with first dimension stripped.

So here is what I'd like to have

```
template <typename element, int dimensions>
class MMapMatrixTemplate{
public:
    typedef boost::multi_array_ref<element, dimensions> array_type; 
    typedef std::array<size_t, dimensions> index_type;
    typedef array_type::array_view<dimensions-1>::type stride_type;
};
```

Where `array_type` defines array that is managed by this class `index_type` defines type used to index arrays, and I'd like `` `stride_type `` to define a slice of this array having one less dimension.

For now I get an error:

```
  include/MMapMatrix.hh:31:55: error: non-template ‘array_view’ used as template
   typedef boost::multi_array_ref<element, dimensions>::array_view<dimensions-1>::type stride_type;
                                                   ^
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_generators) on views, you can see the definition of the view type as:

```
  typedef typename Array::template array_view<3>::type view1_t;
```

so this makes your code compile:

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

template <typename element, int dimensions>
class MMapMatrixTemplate{
public:

    typedef boost::multi_array_ref<element, dimensions> array_type; 

    typedef std::array<size_t, dimensions> index_type;

    //typedef array_type::array_view<dimensions-1>::type stride_type;
    typedef typename array_type::template array_view<dimensions-1>::type stride_type;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    typedef MMapMatrixTemplate<double, 4> matrix;

    return 0;
}
```

You need to specify that the `array_view` is actually a *class template* in order to use it as such. Otherwise, the compiler expects it to be fully defined type.

Comment: genius, this problem has confused me a long time, and boost lib is really not convenient to use

Answer (score 4):

You need `typename` and/or `.template` qualification on dependent names:

```
typedef typename array_type::array_view<dimensions-1>::type stride_type;
```

If you're using a template member on a dependent name, you need `.template` qualification:

```
obj.template foo<T>();
```

See this very popular answer for background

#### [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132)